# How can I change size of xml file in the stage in Flash/AS3?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I know you can use .width or . height properties, but that seems so sloppy. I need to change this:

```
function packetF(): void {
        Time.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, checkF);
        Image = Data.image[imageNum].imgURL;
        Childnumber = Data.*.length();

        imgW = Data.image[imageNum].imgW;
        imgH = Data.image[imageNum].imhH;

        imageLoad = new Loader;
        imageLoad.load(new URLRequest(Image));
        imagebox.addChild(imageLoad);
        imageLoad.x=(imagebox.width - Number(imgW))/2;
        imageLoad.y=(imagebox.height - Number(imgH))/2;
    }
```

and I have no specific height/width yet. I just need to know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Loading a file (image in this case) is an asynchronous process. You cannot change the width and height until after the image has loaded:

```
import flash.events.Event;

function packetF(): void 
{
    Time.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, checkF);
    Image = Data.image[imageNum].imgURL;
    Childnumber = Data.*.length();

    imgW = Data.image[imageNum].imgW;
    imgH = Data.image[imageNum].imhH;

    imageLoad = new Loader();
    // listen for Event.COMPLETE on the loader:
    imageLoad.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);
    imageLoad.load(new URLRequest(Image));
    imagebox.addChild(imageLoad);
    imageLoad.x=(imagebox.width - Number(imgW))/2;
    imageLoad.y=(imagebox.height - Number(imgH))/2;
}

function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void 
{
    imageLoad.width = imgW;
    imageLoad.height = imgH;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The area I was changing was the imagebox (the MovieClip where I'm loading the image).Your advice is appreciated!

Comment: In that case, you should be able to change `imageLoad.width` to `imageBox.width` and it should work.